# LibGDX - problem with AssetLoader

Tags: java, android, libgdx

can someone tell me where i make a mistake? i want to use AssetLoader to load textures but.... always have the same error. I thought that problem is with my game so I made new project but I still have error.

> Couldn't load dependencies of asset: assets/badlogic.jpg

Here is my code:

```
public class TestApp extends ApplicationAdapter {
   SpriteBatch batch;
   Texture img;

   @Override
   public void create () {
      Assets.load();
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
      img = Assets.manager.get(Assets.image, Texture.class);
   }

   @Override
   public void render () {
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
      batch.end();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose () {
      batch.dispose();
      img.dispose();
   }
}

public class Assets {

    public static final AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static final String image = "assets/badlogic.jpg";

    public static void load(){
        manager.load(image, Texture.class);
        manager.finishLoading();
    }

    public static void dispose(){
        manager.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read LibGDX's guide for plugging your assets folder to your IDE:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-intellij-idea

Especially **Linking the asset directories** part.

Everything in code seems ok.

Comment: I changed path from "assets/badlogic.jpg" to "badlogic.jpg" and everything works. But when I use manager.getProgress() console all thime show me that progress is 1.0 even if Im asking for Progress() before load() method.

Comment: manager.finishLoading() finishes loading immediately and sets the progress to 1.0 :)

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with the image's path. Try and find what might be wrong with it.